# Executing 'tail -f' with Capistrano 3 pipes nothing into output

Tags: ruby, capistrano, tail

I have a Capistrano task that looks like this:

```
desc "tail log file"
task :tail do
  on roles(:app) do
    execute "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/#{fetch(:log_file)}.log"
  end
end
```

When I run the task, it proceeds with the blocking tail -f request, but it shows up nothing. I am one hundred percent sure that it simply does not pipe the data somehow (I've verified it - the log file gets updated on the remote) thus it shows nothing. Did I miss something?
The app role is included in the stage config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround/solution to my problem. I don't remember where I did found the solution, but executing the command *rawly* by instantiating an ssh connection with a pseudo-tty forced allocation (that's the `-t`) got it working. That will get the blocking requests like `tail -f` working. As the `man` pages say on the `-t` option:

> This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine,
>                which can be very useful...

```
def execute_interactively(command)
  user = fetch(:user)
  port = fetch(:port)
  cmd = "ssh -l #{user} #{host} -p #{port} -t 'cd #{deploy_to}/current && #{command}'"
  exec cmd
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmmmm..., check the permissions in the file system.  The user that runs the task should have the permission to read the file.

You can try chmod o+r logfile.log

Here you're giving permissions to read to anybody on the file (Useful for debugging purposes).

Comment: The permissions are set properly. The file has the `-rw-r--r--` permissions, so anyone can read it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the capistrano verbosity level to `DEBUG` to see any streaming output. I found the solution in the [capistrano3-taillog](https://github.com/taka0125/capistrano3-taillog) gem; see [taillog.cap](https://github.com/taka0125/capistrano3-taillog/blob/8cde1261a92e6bbf38feb63c5ca0b178c0662d4e/lib/capistrano3/tasks/taillog.cap).

```
desc "tail log file"
task :tail do
  on roles(:app) do
    with_verbosity Logger::DEBUG do
      execute "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/#{fetch(:log_file)}.log"
    end
  end
end

def with_verbosity(output_verbosity)
  old_verbosity = SSHKit.config.output_verbosity
  begin
    SSHKit.config.output_verbosity = output_verbosity
    yield
  ensure
    SSHKit.config.output_verbosity = old_verbosity
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey @CMaresh did not work , I used exactly this code in capistrano3

Comment: Does it work when you run capistrano with logging level of debug set in your `deploy.rb`? Try adding `set :log_level, :debug` in your `deploy.rb` to ensure tailing works by itself.